# Alternate approach to finding centre of mass of hollow hemisphere?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, mass

I found out a different method for integrating the center of mass of a hollow hemisphere by taking semicircular rings as an elementary part of our hollow hemisphere and then taking the ring's Center of mass's as point masses and joining all the Center of mass's of all the rings and hence forming another semicircular disc of all the Center of mass's whose radius is $\frac{2R}{\pi}$ which is the center of mass of all the initial discs...and hence we have a new disc whose radius is $\frac{2R}{\pi}$ and mass same as the hemisphere and therefore this disc's com is at $\frac{2}{\pi}\left(\frac{2R}{\pi}\right)$ which is $\frac{4R}{\pi^2}$ but the actual answer is $\frac{r}{2}$...So if any of you understand my problem and know what I did wrong then plz help me out here....the whole solution is again shown in the image visually...[image]

Comment: I don't see why you get rings. If you cut your half sphere into part which look more like a piece of cake than a hand ring. So like this (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_cHfk3cMS-w) without the inner volume.

Comment: you cannot make a sphere out of flat rings, the rings need to become thicker as they  come closer to the plane. Plus you did not show any integration

Comment: Having said this, your question does not really conform with our policy of "where am I wrong" kind of questions, https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18242/what-is-the-policy-here-on-homework

Comment: i would guess that the error comes from counting the mass of the tiny endpoints of the semicircles multiple times.